# To monitor and control remote server via SMS using two different softwares

Tags: c#, php, server, remote-server, gsm

Is it possible to create an appliaction that can receive command in SMS form from a remote user to control server also to receive automated SMS alert from the server?I would like to know in term of using GSM modem too

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. You can do this in many ways.
The easiest way is look for "SMS inbound service". 
In that service you get a phone number to send SMS and you put one URI to callback, when you send a SMS, the service callback to your URI.
When your page is called, you can do anything you want, but you need programming skills